# Tracking traffic going through 3rd party website on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

According to [Domains & Directories](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsDomains) from Google Analytic's documentation, having non-customized tracking code on *www.example.com* and *dogtoy.example.com* would provide inaccurate referrals and visitor counts.

Enabling cross domain tracking would solve the problem, but what should I do when I cannot insert modified tracking code on *dogtoy.example.com*? (or when a user go through a third party payment processor, more realistically)

How can I maintain data integrity on traffic referrals, visit count, visitor flow, etc when users go through processes like:

www.example.com --> 3rd party payment processor --> www.example.com/thank_you

I am using analytics.js (Universal Analytics). 
Would it be a different concept or would it be any easier if I use ga.js?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I have gathered enough information, so I'm answering my own question.

Let's say there are two scenarios of user flow:

1. www.example.com -> dogtoy.example.com -> www.example.com/thank_you
2. www.example.com -> paymentsite.com -> www.example.com/tahnk_you

In both scenarios, tracking code is embedded only on pages under www.examples.com.

---

I shouldn't stress out too much because Google Analytics (GA) will handle both scenarios pretty well.

According to [Google Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1257084?hl=en#visits_vs_visitors) page:

> Visits represent the number of individual sessions initiated by all
>   the visitors to your site. If a user is inactive on your site for 30
>   minutes or more, any future activity is attributed to a new session.
>   Users that leave your site and return within 30 minutes are counted as
>   part of the original session.

Two domains, *dogoty.example.com* and *paymentsite.com*, are indeed referral sources for traffic coming back to *www.example.com*. However, GA ignores the referral sources as long as a visit is still open (i.e. session cookie is not overwritten).

Therefore, credit is given to the original referral source which brought a user to *www.example.com* in a first place.

Unlike traditional GA, Universal Analytics (analytics.js) does not ignore referral sources like traditional GA (ga.js) does. However simple settings on admin page will take care of the issue.

[Universal Analytics usage guideline](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en) states:

> By default, all referrals trigger a new session in UA. For example, if
>   a visitor is on your site, leaves but then immediately returns, this
>   visitor has logged 2 sessions. You can, however, modify your tracking
>   code to exclude all traffic from specific domains as referral traffic
>   with the referral exclusions.

For understanding a concept of how GA tracks traffic, this page was also helpful. 
[How Visits are calculated in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?topic=2524483&ctx=topic&hl=en)